# Can't start Azure Interactive mode

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

The command failed with an unexpected error.
Here is the traceback:

```
No module named 'prompt_toolkit.interface'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 233, in invoke
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 663, in execute
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 726, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 697, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 333, in __call__
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/interactive/custom.py", line 41, in start_shell
  File "C:\Users\zahari.mladenov\.azure\cliextensions\interactive\azext_interactive\__init__.py", line 10, in start_shell
    from .azclishell.app import AzInteractiveShell
  File "C:\Users\zahari.mladenov\.azure\cliextensions\interactive\azext_interactive\azclishell\app.py", line 33, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.interface import Application, CommandLineInterface
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit.interface'
To open an issue, please run: 'az feedback'
```

I am trying to run azure interactive mode but every time it displays these errors, any idea how to fix them?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the prompt_toolkit.interface with `pip install promp_toolkit`, mounting it to another storage account through the Azure portal, installed the Azure CLI entirely from scratch on my machine locally but nothing seems to work. My Python version is 3.10 and all the Azure CLI versions are up to date. If anyone can help me resolve this problem it would be great, because I am new to Azure Powershell and interactive mode really helps me learn the new commands and how to write.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the command `az interactive` either in Local Windows PowerShell or Azure CLI Command Prompt, I'm getting the same error because of `az` module version `2.41.0`.

[image]

Then I have upgraded the `az` module to `2.42.0` and then run the cmdlet `az interactive` in both Windows PowerShell and Azure CLI Command prompt locally:

**Windows PowerShell**:

[image]

**Azure CLI Command Prompt Locally**:

[image]

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/interactive-azure-cli) of interactive-azure-cli for more information.